# Find all subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_3\oplus \mathbb{Z}_3\oplus \mathbb{Z}_3\oplus \mathbb{Z}_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ denote the group $\mathbb{Z}_3\oplus\mathbb{Z}_3\oplus \mathbb{Z}_3\oplus\mathbb{Z}_3$, try to find all subgroups of it

I think it may be quite similar to the extension of finite fields since $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is also a finite field, so we can regard $G$ as a four dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_3$, so all subgroups are exactly subspaces?

I wonder whether it’s correct or false, and how to use it to solve this problem.

Comment: Counting subspaces sounds like an excellent idea, but why "invariant" subspaces?

Comment: Invariant under what?

Comment: @Muses_China More than that, I think.  There are $14$ non-trivial subgroups just choosing factors of the direct sum.  In addition, there are whole families of subgroups generated by elements such as $(1, 2, 0, 0)$ or $(1, 0, 2, 0)$, etc.

Comment: @Robert Shore Sorry, I made a silly mistake.

Comment: Also see: $q$-binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're correct that every additive subgroup of $G$ is also a vector space over $\Bbb Z_3$.  That's because the only non-zero scalars are $1$ and $2=1+1$, so closure under addition implies closure under scalar multiplication, and it's not hard to verify that the necessary distributive properties also hold.

Each non-zero element $g \in G$ defines a subspace of dimension $1$ and a subspace of dimension $3$.  The latter subspace is the set of elements perpendicular to $g$ using the obvious dot product.  Both $g$ and $2g$ define the same two subspaces, so there are $40$ subgroups of order $3$ and $40$ subgroups of order $27$.

Now choose $g, h \in G$ such that $S= \{ g, h \}$ is linearly independent.  There are $\frac{80 \cdot 78}{2}=3120$ such subsets  Then $S$ defines a subgroup of order $9$.  However, each subgroup of order $9$ has $\frac{8 \cdot 6}{2} = 24$ different bases, so there are $130$ different subgroups of order $9$.  Thus, $G$ has a total of $210$ non-trivial proper subgroups.  Listing them is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: For what it's worth, I confirm this number (though I did it slightly differently). There is also the trivial subgroup and the original group, so there are 212 subgroups in total.

Comment: The trivial subgroup of a group normally refers to the subgroup that contains only the identity, so in fact there are $211$ nontrivial subgroups. But why not avoid the confusion by just saying that there are a total of $212$ subgroups?

Comment: @DerekHolt Forgot the word proper.  Added now.